# Associating an app with appProtection policy using microsoft graph api gives bad request response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Invoking the endpoint

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections/{appProtectionPolicyId}/mobileAppIdentifierDeployments`

with body

```json
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppIdentifierDeployment",
    "mobileAppIdentifier": {
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.mobileAppIdentifier"
    },
    "id": "com.microsoft.office.outlook.android",
    "version": "1146701235"
}
```

returns a `400 Bad Request` response:

```json
"error": {
    "code": "No method match route template",
    "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation/key/navigation with http verb POST for request /MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections('T_6c3e5440-9a81-4f8b-88dd-1e83c9e6bc1f')/mobileAppIdentifierDeployments.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "8b8579c6-6992-46c0-8222-b1fbd13388e4",
        "date": "2017-10-09T06:34:34"
    }
}
```

What am I missing in the request?

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint should be `updateMobileAppIdentifierDeployments` rather than `mobileAppIdentifierDeployments`:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections/{androidManagedAppProtectionId}/updateMobileAppIdentifierDeployments`

The request body is also missing the full `mobileAppIdentifierDeployments` object:

```json
{
    "mobileAppIdentifierDeployments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppIdentifierDeployment",
        "mobileAppIdentifier": {
          "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.androidMobileAppIdentifier"
        },
        "id": "5a77f582-f582-5a77-82f5-775a82f5775a",
        "version": "Version value"
      }
    ]
}
```

*This method is documented @ [updateMobileAppIdentifierDeployments action](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_androidmanagedappprotection_updatemobileappidentifierdeployments)*

Comment: Where can a get app id and version for above api, Currently I am using the ones returned by https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/  but it does not work, I am getting the same error as in previous comment.

Comment: It worked using the below request body `{
  "mobileAppIdentifierDeployments": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppIdentifierDeployment",
      "mobileAppIdentifier": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidMobileAppIdentifier"
      },
      "id": "com.microsoft.skydrive.android",
      "version": "version guid"
    }
  ]
}`  The id and version of the app is fetched from endpoint